# Adding mysql value

Tags: php, mysql, math

all im try do do is add variables that are within mysql.

I thought this would be simple but not proving to be and im not really getting anywhere.

Is it even possible to add values from mysql?

I'm sure it probably something simple, as always, any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID ='$userid'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows ==1){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  $id = $row['uid'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $angles = $row['angles'];
  $decimals = $row['decimals'];
  $multiplication = $row['multiplication'];
  $probability = $row['probability'];
      $sequences = $row['sequences'];
  $symmetry = $row['symmetry'];

 }
$sum = $sequences + $symmetry;
    print ("$sum");
```

Solved the issue. the query should read ....WHERE uid ='$userid'");!

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: You're not checking whether you had mysql errors or not. You didn't even check whether your if condition evaluated to true.. nor did you post the results (errors) you get back. Very sloppy, you should test thoroughly on your own before asking for guidance tbh.

Comment: sequences and symmetry are ints, 75 and 50. But sum is printing 0.

Comment: If `$sum = 0` then `$numrows = 0` or `$numrows > 1` Try using the `LIMIT 1`

Comment: its definitely able to connect to the database. Echoing out 'name'  works fine. Doesn't want to echo out symmetry, probability.. by themselves though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the calculation by the database by a query like this:

```
SELECT uid, name, angles, (sequences + symmetry) AS mysum FROM users WHERE ID ='$userid'
```